# how to set continous working gauge bar in j2me application? symbian

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, lcdui

I have seen progress bar in mobile which are working continuously while processing data in the background.

Comment: Did you use the gauge example from below for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/alerts20/index.html

```
new Gauge( null, false,
                            Gauge.INDEFINITE,
                            Gauge.CONTINUOUS_RUNNING );
```

Comment: i have seen application in which page opacity become dull and progress bar is running in the bottom... how would i do that...